# How to get all session variables which name starts with a particular string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am developing an application in ASP.NET using C#. In my code I am creating multiple sessions. In the next page I want to get all the session value which names starts with a particular string. How can  I do that?

Suppose in my page I am creating 5 sessions with session name `gs_text1` to `gs_text5` and creating another 10 sessions with name like `es_label1` to `es_label10`. Now on the next page I want to add some value to all the sessions which name starts with `es`. How can I do that in ASP.NET?

Comment: Do you mean an actual ASP.NET Session, or some "session" based on your business domain?

Comment: @ColinMackay Actually I am talking about the ASP.Net session variable, which will be operated from code behind.

Answer (score 2):

An [HttpSessionState object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.keys.aspx) has a property on it called `Keys` which will return the keys for all the items you've put in session. You can search these keys with linq or something to get all the keys that start with a given value. YOu can then loop through them and do whatever it is that you want to do.

```
var requiredKeys = Session.Keys.Where(x=>x.StartsWith("es"));
foreach (var key in requiredKeys)
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```

N.B. When you say you are creating "5 sessions with session name [blah]" I assume you mean you are putting objects into the session with those names as keys. If this isn't what you mean then you might need to go back and explain why you are creating multiple sessions so we can understand better...

Comment: I have tried to use your code but it is not working actually it is giving me an error, it is displaying that "there are no definition of Where". I am declaring the session variable like 
        "Session["es_label1"] = hfESTitle.Value.Trim();
        Session["es_label2"] = hfESPhoneNumber.Value.Trim();"

Comment: Where is an extension method on Enumerable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx). You may need to include a `using System.Linq` for it to work or if you are using an old version of C#/.NET you may not have it available to you. The main thing though is that Session.Keys contains all the keys and you can loop over them and use the string `StartsWith` method to determine if it is one you want or not.